# Ways to find out uptime of Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, reboot, watchos

Having to enter a PIN code could possibly mean that wristband wasn't tight enough. Or Apple Watch booted. That question could be easy to answer had Apple provided uptime information directly. Alas, Apple didn't. Any workarounds?

I only found an advice to check graph of the battery use, but given its scale and the fact that AW boots take minute or so I doubt it would reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to the answer actually should go to one my buddy (thanks again, Max!) who drew my attention to that fact that both iOS and WatchOS actually have *diagnostic logs*.

So I just run "Watch" app on iPhone and under *General/Diagnostic Logs* found a file named *panic-base-2021-01-18-093103.ips*. A self-speaking excerpt from its content follows:

```
  "panicString" : "Unexpected SoC (system) watchdog reset occurred"
```